# how to recycle image from ListView in Android using custom ListAdapter and Cache View

Tags: java, android, listview

my app that i am working seem to getting a error say that i am running out of ram. its  seem working  up to point then i scroll some more and and  it run out of memory. i need to recycle the image in the list when the user scroll past them. but i just don't know where to begin recycle

i am using the code from this tut 
[this is the code i am using](http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error in the adapter:

```
convertView = ( RelativeLayout ) inflater.inflate( resource, null );
```

you have to check if `convertView` is `null` and only if it is - create a new View, otherwise use `convertView` given from method params

Comment: i am confused. i made a if statement "if(convertView==null)" wrap it around must of code, i feel im heading in the wrong path. any help would be great

Comment: @soad666p well I think i misunderstood you, as there are more than one adapter in the code you referenced a link to. So, forget about `null`-wrapping and try to do this: now you save in `City` image as `String`, that is not really optimized, you'd better save resourse ID and use it later for method `setImageResource` of an `ImageView`. Doing this you will save extra memory, that you allocate to `Drawable`.

Comment: something along the line of "int id = getResources().getIdentifier("yourpackagename:drawable/" + StringGenerated, null, null);" ,"imageview.setImageResource(id);"

Answer (score 0):

The pattern they're implementing it's called 'Holder Pattern', and It's used to make thing load faster when having a lot of Views in a ListView, anyway, you should chekout [LRU Cache Android - API 12](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

They use a very efficient way to load images, first looking for them in the Cache Memory, if it's available in the Cache, we load from there, If not we load the Image and add it. To the cache.!

Comment: Ok so i should allow the app to cache the image that i will use to the phone first. is right. [link](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)`!link`

Comment: you could create an CacheManager by yourself. By somehow, retaining the references in a List or a HashMap, actually, I Think LruCache implementation uses a HashMap to store the Objects.